# Interactive Javascript console (preferably integrated with Firebug)

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

I'm looking for a way to have an interactive JIT debugger, preferably integrated with Firebug.

I got the idea from PHPEd, which has an "Immediate" debug tab where you can just type in PHP code and modify objects on the fly. This makes debugging a breeze as you can re-assign variables multiple times, re-execute functions, etc without leaving the program.

Here's what I think would be superb:
 - set a breakpoint in Firebug
 - arrive to breakpoint
 - have an Execute JS tab where one could enter JS code, similar to what I described above

Does anything like this exist already?

TIA.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can already do this in Firebug.  Just get to a break point, then go to the "console" tab, and type your commands into the command line at the bottom (where there's the ">>>").

Comment: Ah, the console was disabled in Firebug and it escaped my attention. Thanks, everyone for an amazingly quick response. Everyone gets a cookie!

Comment: You can do this in Google Chrome too, just open it up and press Ctrl + Shift + j

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question correctly, I think can do that already in firebug.

- Set a breakpoint (or use the debugger
  keyword)
- Click the console tab
- the bottom line allows you to enter a
  javascript command.
- if you need more space click the icon
  that looks like an upside down v in
  the bottom right part of the browser.

You might also like the [JS execute extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1729).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Firebug can do this and it's only a matter of a little investigation [on their website](http://getfirebug.com/) to find out how to do this best :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with parents that Firebug is the best choice.  Another option that requires a good deal of configuration would be [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/).  For folks using the Eclipse IDE, Aptana is a solid editor for Javascript work.  The plus with Aptana is that it's tied more to a code editing environment.