# What's a good way to run Javascript Interactively?

Tags: javascript, interactive

For Ruby, we have irb.  For Python, we have IDLE.  For Javascript, is Firebug or Chrome on a blank page the best way to run or test Javascript interactively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822071/interactive-javascript-console-preferably-integrated-with-firebug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the alternatives already mentioned by [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162333/whats-a-good-way-to-run-javascript-interactively/3162341#3162341):

On the browser:

- [JSConsole](http://jsconsole.com) (excellent for workshops)
- [JHP](http://www.3site.eu/jstests/jhp/)

<sub>Both with basic auto-completion.</sub>

Standalone consoles:

- [JSDB](http://www.jsdb.org/) (SpiderMonkey based)
- [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)

Comment: JSConsole is really good because it can show the whole object's content, like Ruby's inspect() or what is shown in irb

Comment: You could also use `node-repl` or Apple's `jsc`, if you're on a Mac. I have a little bit more on my blog: http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2009/09/javascript-console/

Answer (score 6):

You can also visit [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

On the iPhone, there is JSanywhere (it seems written by a Japanese author).

There is not much information about it on Google in English, but it can be downloaded for free from the App Store.

Comment: JSBin and JSFiddle are really nice too.  JSConsole might be closer to an interactive console like irb or IDLE.

Comment: JSBin worked for me to run just JS code without HTML, but JSFiddle didn't

Answer (score 0):

The 'shell' and 'jsenv' bookmarklets from squarefree work well:

https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html

I prefer to use a bookmarklet so I can work in the environment of the current page.

Firebug addicts can use Firebug Light in other browsers: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

However nothing beats the modern browser built-in debuggers for:

- error messages from timeouts
- line numbers of errors
- addings breakpoints
- live scope inspection

Answer (score 0):

As of 2013, there is a good comparison of the available options here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/

Also interesting:

http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/codepen-jsfiddle-jsbin/#post-134290

Tldr;

- [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) may be the "best-looking feature-packed playground". Seems to be under constant development; strong on social features.
- [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/1/edit) appears to be the only option offering a real interactive console.
- Details matter; the discussion in the [CSS Tricks forum](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/codepen-jsfiddle-jsbin/#post-134290) (see above) is particularly helpful in that regard.