# Enter doesn't submit commands in console at breakpoint

Tags: firefox

On Firefox 37.0.2 for Linux Mint Rebecca 17.1 (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

When I hit a breakpoint, the console is permanently in multi-line command mode and <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't submit a command, but opens a new line.

So when I type `console.log("foo")

[image: type a command]

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than seeing the output `foo` I get:

[image: enter opens new line]

I've tried putting a semi-colon at the end of the command, pressing every imaginable combination of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> etc. but they all just open a new line.

The console works as expected when I'm not at a breakpoint. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822083/2071807) suggests it shouldn't be a problem.

What's going on?

Comment: I don't have this problem in Firefox 39.0 so I suppose I should delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to have gone away in Firefox 39.0.

So if you're experiencing it, maybe the best thing to do is to upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a better answer, but closing Firefox and restarting it solved this problem for me. You can then go to the History menu and restore the previous session to get back to where you were.

I'm almost certain this is a bug since Mozilla's own documentation only mentions that to type more than 1 line before executing the input you have to press Shift+Enter instead of just Enter.